# Why can't .each() find the child elements?

Tags: jquery, forms, each

`e.target` points to a form element. I'm trying to iterate through each input element and collect the name and value so I can pass them as an argument to  `a .load()`. The `.each()` iterator never finds the `<input>` elements, and therefore quits without processing anything. The form contains one `div` element which contains the inputs.

```
var formData = {};
$(e.target).has(":input").each(function(){
    formData[$(this).name] = $(this).value;
});
```

The form html:

```
<div id="partner-settings-form" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 67.6875px; height: auto;">         
<article class="sign_in form-dialog clearfix">
      <div class="bg-form-dlg">
        <div class="col_100 clearfix">
<h2>UPS Shipping Information</h2>
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="sign_in_form sign_up_form" action="" method="post"><div class="zend_form">

<input type="hidden" name="partnerId" value="2" id="partnerId">
<div class="shippingdetails"><fieldset id="fieldset-account">
<div id="key-label" class="formlabel"><label for="key" class="required">Access Key: *</label></div>
<div id="key-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="key" id="key" value="..."></div>
<div id="id-label" class="formlabel"><label for="id" class="required">User ID: *</label></div>
<div id="id-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="..."></div>
<div id="password-label" class="formlabel"><label for="password" class="required">Password: *</label></div>
<div id="password-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="..."></div>
<div id="account_number-label" class="formlabel"><label for="account_number" class="required">Account Number: *</label></div>
<div id="account_number-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="account_number" id="account_number" value="..."></div>
<div id="address1-label" class="formlabel"><label for="address1" class="required">Address1: *</label></div>
<div id="address1-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" value="..."></div>
<div id="address2-label" class="formlabel"><label for="address2" class="optional">Address2:</label></div>
<div id="address2-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" value=""></div>
<div id="phone-label" class="formlabel"><label for="phone" class="required">Phone: *</label></div>
<div id="phone-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="..."></div>
<div id="city-label" class="formlabel"><label for="city" class="required">City: *</label></div>
<div id="city-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="Los Angeles"></div>
<div id="state-label" class="formlabel"><label for="state" class="required">State (code): *</label></div>
<div id="state-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="state" id="state" value="CA"></div>
<div id="country-label" class="formlabel"><label for="country" class="optional">Country:</label></div>
<div id="country-element" class="formcontent">
<select name="country" id="country" class="dlg-select">
    <option value="US" label="UNITED STATES" selected="selected">UNITED STATES</option>
    <option value="AF" label="AFGHANISTAN">AFGHANISTAN</option>
    <option value="..." label="...">...</option>
</select></div>
<div id="postal-label" class="formlabel"><label for="postal" class="required">Postal Code: *</label></div>
<div id="postal-element" class="formcontent">
<input type="text" name="postal" id="postal" value="90036"></div></fieldset></div>
<div>
<p><label id="configship-label">&nbsp;</label>
<input type="submit" name="configship" id="configship" value="Save Information"></p></div></div></form></div>
</div>
</article>

    </div>
```

Comment: `$(e.target).children("input").each(function(){ formData[$(this).name] = $(this).value; });`

Comment: What the hell is `formData` ?

Comment: Btw, `$.has()` returns boolean, if a selector is matched and found inside the parent selector. You should use: `$.find()` instead.

Comment: @ZlatanO. no has() method reduce the set of matched set of elements according to descendants and selector used

Comment: @roasted Okay. But still that does not solve the problem.

Comment: @ZlatanO. you are right, he should use .find() indeed

Comment: @DanielGimenez Adding .children("input") did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try differently then

```
$(e.target).find('input').each();
```

Comment: Do you have any other ideas? Please review my form html for a better understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Use [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) for that, no need to re-invent the wheel, mate.

```
$(e.target).serialize();
```

**EDIT:**

Since .load() requests GET with a query-string, and POST with an object, .serialize() wont cut it. The workaround is to either use .ajax() or tweak your code, since you got errors:

```
var formData = {};
$(e.target).find('input').each(function() {
    formData[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();  // .attr('name') and .val() instead.
});
```

Comment: Doen't serialize gives you a query string? (`a=b&c=d`) Think op wants: `{a: 'b', c: 'd'}`

Comment: He want to pass it to load(), and since it is a URL-encoded string already, it will work.

Comment: Depends on what op have to do on the server-side... If the values should be under the same namespace your example would work: `{payload: {a: 'b', c: 'd'}}` -> `payload[a]=b&payload[c]=d`

Comment: I can't use .serialize(). I need to pass an object to trigger a POST.

Comment: @ChrisBarnhill No you don't. The AJAX call suspects either a URL-encoded string, or an object. If an object is passed, it gets **serialized** first. Check the [documentation for $.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), on the `data` part.

Comment: I'm not using .ajax(). I'm using .load().

Comment: @ChrisBarnhill `.load()` is just a short-cut wrapper for `.ajax()`. Please try serialize() out, and you'll see it works. And BTW, you cannot make a POST-request with .load(), it is only for **GET**.

Comment: From jQuery .load docs: Request Method

The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

Comment: @ChrisBarnhill Oh, how cool isn't that! My apology for that. Instead of .has(), use find(), and also you need to use `.attr('name')` and `.val()` to get the name and value of the input!

Comment: @ChrisBarnhill Check my latest edit. That shall work, if not, then there's something peculiar with your code I cannot figure out :-)

Comment: @Eric Did you take a look at the form html I added to my original question? It may give you some insight on the problem.